# What are the solutions of $y^6-\alpha^6 =0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$. I need to find the solution of the differential equation
$$y^{(6)}-\alpha^6 y =0.$$
I consider characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^6-\alpha^6 $. I need to find the solutions of $p(\lambda)=0$, i.e. I need to solve
$$\lambda^6-\alpha^6 =0.$$

What are the solutions of this equation? And with what multiplicities?
Sure it has the solutions $\lambda = \pm\alpha$, but what about the other solutions?

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The equation in the question is not the same as the equation in the title!

Answer (score 2):

You wrote the characteristic polynomial wrong, since the default $y$ function has characteristic polynomial equal to $0$. As such, you have
\begin{align}
\lambda ^6 - a^6 = 0.
\end{align}

We must take scenarios:

- If $a=0$ we have
  \begin{align}
  y^{(6)} (x) = 0 
  \end{align}
  which by integrating $6$ times, we get
  \begin{align}
  \boxed{y(x)=C_{1}\,x^{5}+C_{2}\,x^{4}+C_{3}\,x^{3}+C_{4}\,x^{2}+C_{5}\,x+C_{6}}.
  \end{align}
- If $a \neq 0 $, we get
  \begin{align}
  \lambda^6 - a^6 = 0 \implies
  \begin{cases}
  \lambda_1 = a\\
  \lambda_2 = -a
  \end{cases}
  \end{align}
  which can be solved by trivial integral calculus, namely
  \begin{align}
  y^{(6)} = a^6 &\implies \int y^{(6)} (x) dx = \int a^6 dx\\
  &\implies y^{(5)}(x) = a^6 x + C_1\\
  &\implies \int y^{(5)}(x) dx = \int (a^6 x + C_1)dx\\
  &\implies  \text{integrate 5 more times}\\
  &\implies \boxed{y(x)=\dfrac{a^{6}\,x^{6}}{720}+C_{1}\,x^{5}+C_{2}\,x^{4}+C_{3}\,x^{3}+C_{4}\,x^{2}+C_{5}\,x+C_{6}}.
  \end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. When $a\neq 0$, shouldn’t that be the solution? $y=e^{\alpha x}(c_1 +c_2 x+c_3 x^2 +c_4 x^3 +c_5 x^4 +c_6 x^5)$ for $y=\alpha$ and $y=e^{-\alpha x}(c_1 +c_2 x+c_3 x^2 +c_4 x^3 +c_5 x^4 +c_6 x^5)$ for $y=-\alpha$?

Comment: Your second formula also applies to the case $\alpha=0$ (or $a=0$; the OP seems undecided).

Comment: Oops, $y^{(6)}$ needs to be $a^6 y$, not $a^6$. But the OP seems to be confused about this too.

Comment: @TonyK, I edited my comment, sorry. Clearly holds also in the case $\alpha=0$ and they reduce ti the one written by algevristis for the case $\alpha=0$. Are my solutions correct?

Comment: @User1010: until you stop changing your question, we can't really be sure. At the moment it is inconsistent.

Comment: @TonyK you are right and I know, I just wrote it down for the sake of completeness. As for OP, I do not follow his line of thinking since he changed it at least 4 times.

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda^6 - \alpha^6 =0\implies \lambda = \alpha e^{\frac {2k\pi i}{6}}$

Or, if you want to avoid using complex numbers...

$\lambda^6 - \alpha^6 = (\lambda^3-\alpha^3)(\lambda^2+\alpha^3) = (\lambda - \alpha)(\lambda^2 + \alpha\lambda +\lambda^2)(\lambda+\alpha)(\lambda^2-\alpha\lambda + \alpha^2)=0$